# How to make a select with array contains value clause in psql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have column `arr`  which is of type `array`.

I need to get rows, where `arr` column contains value `s`

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE arr @> ARRAY['s']
```

gives the error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]

Why does it not work?

p.s. I know about `any()` operator, but why doesn't `@>` work?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE arr @> ARRAY['s']::varchar[]
```

Comment: Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html

Answer (score 92):

Note that this may also work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE s=ANY(array)
```

Comment: And this also prevents me from needing to cast to varchar, as in `s @> ARRAY['constant'::varchar]`, shorter.

Comment: This won't use the GIN index so I wouldst use it. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Worked for me in PostgreSQL 14.

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE arr && '{s}'::text[];
```

Compare two arrays for containment.