# Query for array type field on Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm not sure how to do write a query. The issue:

I have two tables, `authorities` and `notices` each one with this column:

```
t.string "tags",   default:[],   array:true
```

I need to check if at least one element from the `authorities` array is in the `notices` array and save it on a class variable. So far I've tried this line of code in my controller:

```
@noticias = Notice.where('tags @> ARRAY[?]',current_authority.tags)
```

I tried something like this in the view:

```
<% @noticias.each do |notice| %>
    <% notice.nombre %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks for you answers but my problem was

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] @> text[]
```

the solution is:

```
@noticias = Notice.where('tags && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]',current_authority.tags)
```

As explained here [If array contains value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606357/if-array-contains-value)

Comment: don't store arrays in DB. ever

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: Why not? SQL supports arrays, PostgreSQL supports arrays, and so does the Rails4 PostgreSQL interface. It isn't like he's using the `serialize` abomination.

Comment: @muistooshort I never tried to refute it. I just have experience, which showed me that there is always (there should have been written 'almost always', but in my case it is always) a better way, namely associations.

Comment: Denormalization is a common practice when you want to optimize for query time. There is nothing wrong with it, you're just trading off the benefits of normalization. Querying is easy and fast, but deleting / updating is hard - If you want to delete or update a tag, you'll have to go over all parent records and update them. If you want to know usage statistics of tags, this would be hard too. But if you just want to see the tags for a parent and nothing more, storing it in an array is not bad.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use the `overlap` operator rather than `contain`. The `contain` operator `A @> B` means A includes all element of B. If I understand what you're trying to do, you want to check whether the tag array of `Notice` contains any of the tags of the current authority.

You can do this like this:

```
@noticias = Notice.where('tags && ARRAY[?]', current_authority.tags)
```

Here is a link on all array functions in Postgres:
http://postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html