# SQL - filter rows if the array contains a specific items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `letter_count` looking like this:

```
count   letters
2   ["a","b"]
4   ["b","c"]
2   ["a"]
0   ["b"]
6   ["c"]
7   ["d"]
```

I'd like to be able to query only the rows containing a specific letters.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM letter_counter WHERE letters IN ('["a"]')
```

But it fails.

What's the right syntax for this here?

Comment: Serialised data in a database column is a very bad idea, at least in part for the very issue you're encountering now.  If you have control over the database schema you should refactor it to use a dependant table for the letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this select:

```
SELECT * FROM letter_counter 
WHERE(case when position('a' in array_to_string(letters,',')) > 0 then true else false end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT * FROM letter_counter WHERE letters @> ARRAY['a']::varchar[]
```

Or you could spend 5 seconds searching Stack Overflow and just use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606357/if-array-contains-value).