# Postgres - Check if array contains an id

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to determine if a user has voted on a `question`. The user clicks on an upvote/downvote button which makes a request to an API that pulls out their `id` form a cookie and then stores it within an `upvoters` or `downvoters` array. The upvote/downvote logic works as expected -- no problem there -- however, I'm having trouble determining whether or not the `upvoters` or `downvoters` array contains their `id` when the user queries questions by a specific tag.

The question model:

```
 Column                  │ Type                      │  Modifiers
─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────
 key                     │ Serial                    │  PRIMARY KEY
 userid                  │ UUID                      │  NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
 date                    │ TIMESTAMP                 │  WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 answered                │ BOOLEAN                   │  DEFAULT FALSE
 views                   │ INTEGER                   │  DEFAULT 0
 upvoters                | TEXT[]                    |  DEFAULT array[]::text[]
 downvoters              | TEXT[]                    |  DEFAULT array[]::text[]
 title                   | TEXT                      |  NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 uniquetitle             | VARCHAR                   |  NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 body                    | TEXT                      |  NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 tags                    | TEXT[]                    |  DEFAULT array[]::text[]
 comments                | JSONB                     |
```

The API endpoint:

```js
import get from "lodash.get";
import isEmpty from "lodash.isempty";
import db from "~db"; // connection to Postgres using pg-promise

const findAllQuestionsByTagLimitAndOffset = `
  SELECT 
     questions.key, 
     questions.userid, 
     questions.date, 
     questions.body, 
     questions.answered, 
     questions.views, 
     cardinality(questions.upvoters)-cardinality(questions.downvoters) as votes, 
     EXISTS(
       SELECT FROM questions WHERE questions.upvoters @> $4
     ) as upvoted, // check whether or not the logged in user has upvoted this question
     EXISTS(
        SELECT FROM questions WHERE questions.upvoters @> $4
     ) as downvoted, // check whether or not the logged in user has downvoted this question
     questions.title, 
     questions.uniquetitle, 
     questions.tags, 
     users.username, // appends original poster's username
     users.reputation as userrep, // appends original poster's rep
     users.key as userkey // appends original poster's id
  FROM questions 
  INNER JOIN users ON questions.userid=users.id 
  WHERE questions.tags @> $1 
  ORDER BY questions.date DESC 
  LIMIT $2 
  OFFSET $3
`;

/**
 * Fetches questions by tag.
 *
 * @function fetchNewestQuestionsByTag
 * @param {object} req - request object
 * @param {object} res - response object
 * @returns {array} data - questions that contain the queried tag with original poster populated data and some logged in user data
 * @throws {string} err
 */
const fetchNewestQuestionsByTag = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { tag } = req.query;
    if (!tag) throw String("Unable to locate questions because the tag is not valid.");
    const userid = get(req.session, ["id"]);

    const data = await db.any(findAllQuestionsByTagLimitAndOffset, [
      [tag],
      10,
      0,
      [userid],
    ]);
    if (isEmpty(data)) throw String("Unable to locate any questions.");

    res.status(201).send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send(err);
  }
};
```

Here's how the `question` looks after an upvote:

```
answered: false
body: "Test"
date: "2020-06-19T20:24:46.496Z"
downvoters: []
comments: []
title: "Test Title"
tags: ["reactjs"]
uniquetitle: "test-title"
upvoters ["d17a33f4-b26a-11ea-9372-131fa959a01b"] // logged in user id is stored
userid: "d17a33f4-b26a-11ea-9372-131fa959a018"
views: 1
```

After a user has upvoted and refreshes the page and/or queries the question they upvoted by a tag, the following (incorrect) data structure is returned:

```
answered: false
body: "Test"
date: "2020-06-19T20:24:46.496Z"
downvoted: false
tags: ["reactjs"]
title: "Test Title"
uniquetitle: "test-title"
upvoted: false // this should be true as the logged in user is "d17a33f4-b26a-11ea-9372-131fa959a01b" and their id is contained within this array, yet it is still false
userid: "d17a33f4-b26a-11ea-9372-131fa959a018"
userkey: 1
username: "Matt"
userrep: 0
views: 1
votes: 1
```

The problem is that these queries always return false:

```sql
  EXISTS(
    SELECT FROM questions WHERE questions.upvoters @> $4
  ) as upvoted,
  EXISTS(
    SELECT FROM questions WHERE questions.downvoters @> $4
  ) as downvoted,
```

I've tried the following and none of them returns the correct boolean status:

[How to make a select with array contains value clause in psql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606357/how-to-make-a-select-with-array-contains-value-clause-in-psql)

[Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array)

[Postgres: check if array field contains value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value/39643544)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `EXISTS` would check in *all* table rows instead of just the row at hand.

Also, you had `upvoters` twice. Must be `downvoters` for `downvoted`.

I suggest:

```sql
  SELECT 
     q.key, 
     q.userid, 
     q.date, 
     q.body, 
     q.answered, 
     q.views, 
     cardinality(q.upvoters)-cardinality(q.downvoters) AS votes, 
     $4 = ANY (q.upvoters) AS upvoted,
     $4 = ANY (q.downvoters) AS downvoted,
     q.title, 
     q.uniquetitle, 
     q.tags, 
     u.username,
     u.reputation AS userrep,
     u.key as userkey
  FROM   questions q
  JOIN   users     u ON q.userid = u.id 
  WHERE  q.tags @> $1 
  ORDER  BY q.date DESC 
  LIMIT  $2 
  OFFSET $3
```

The array operator `@>` expects *array* types on both sides. Seems like you got that right, passing `[userid]` (constructs an array, right?). With my query, just pass the plain string value `userid`.

`WHERE q.tags @> $1` *may* still make sense as is, if you aim for index usage. See:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns)

Also, `d17a33f4-b26a-11ea-9372-131fa959a01b` suspiciously looks like a **UUID**. Don't use data type `text` / `text[]` for it. Use `uuid` / `uuid[]`. *Much* better in multiple respects. See:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684)

**But** all of these grave issues still cannot explain what you report. You should have seen `true` for both `upvoted` and `downvoted`. There may be more mistakes ...

Comment: `null` means that either `$4` is null, or `$4` contains a valid string and the array `upvoters` contains no match but a null element.